# Static Variables in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have some WCF services. These services run in ASP.NET. I want these services to be able to access a static variable. My problem is, I'm not sure where the appropriate server level storage mechanism is. I don't want to use the database because of speed. But, I want the static variables to stay in memory as long as possible. In fact, I'd like it to stay until I restart my server if it all possible.

Can anyone provide me with any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

You could use static variables in WCF but you must properly synchronize the access to them because they can potentially be accessed from multiple threads concurrently. The values stored in static variables are accessible from everywhere in the AppDomain and remain in memory until the server is restarted.

Comment: But how do I store them in the AppDomain?

Comment: You create a static variable in some class and you access it from your service.

Comment: Is it true only for global static variables, or also for, say, a local variable created at some point when handling the request, that's assigned with a `new` non-static class, which has a static field?

Answer (score 4):

You could have something like this

```
public static class StaticVariables
{
    private static string _variable1Key = "variable1";

    public static Object Variable1
    {
        get 
        {
            return Application[_variable1Key]; 
        }

        set 
        {
            Application[_variable1Key] = value; 
        }
    } 
}
```

The [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) collection itself is thread safe but the stuff you add to it might not be; so keep that in mind.

Comment: How do I get access to the "Application" variable? I don't see it in Intellisense.

Comment: This link should be helpful
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I would be nice to see namespaces included when talking about .NET objects like Application because there are several namespaces and for some people that gets confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If all the services are in a single `ServiceContract` and if all the member variables in your service can be shared across all sessions, then you could set the `ServiceBehavior` to have a [single instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx).

```
[ServiceBehavior( InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single )]
public class MyService : IMyServiceContract
{
}
```