# Sharing a static classes across WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static Variables in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984358/static-variables-in-wcf)

So I am fairly new to using WCF and I have run into the following issue.  I have a class which if not using WCF I would have designed it to be a static class, but I am unsure of how to share a static class across WCF.  Right now I am creating a interface named "IMyClass" and which has the ServiceContract attribute which is how I read to share things across WCF.  Obviously static classes cannot implement interfaces so am I stuck with a non-static class?

Comment: You want that class to be communicated from the server to the client ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still have a static class with static methods that your service implementations call into.

If however you want the service ITSELF to be a singleton service, then you're talking about the [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) of Single. This ensures that only one InstanceContext object is used for all incoming calls and is not recycled subsequent to the calls. If a service object does not exist, one is created.

You would configure this by decorating your service implementation like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Comment: We already have that attribute on the non-static version of the class which I am speak about.  I guess the actual question is "How do you expose static methods across WCF?"

Comment: That is, in essence, what you have done then. The InstanceContextMode of single means that there will only ever be one instance of that service.

Comment: Why do you need a singleton service? It can really impede your scalability...

Comment: Does this attribute also prevent other classes from within library from creating a separate instance of my class?

Comment: Well no, if I understand you correctly. But you would never want another class to instantiate the service directly, but instead to communicate with the service through it's WCF endpoint. Other classes should only know about the contract, not the implementation, otherwise you might as not use WCF.

Comment: I see your point, I think I have to reconsider my design.  Right now we have a number of classes being exposed which *should* have been hidden behind a single class which we expose.  Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if I answered your question.